# Water Pressure Question

Tags: pressure, water

If I put a heavy object in a cup of water will the pressure on the the cup sides near bottom increase versus if no object inserted? Please explain.

Comment: Is the water now deeper?

Answer (score 1):

The water pressure at any point in the cup depends on the depth of water at that point. Placing an object in the cup will increase the depth of water, so the pressure at the same point in the cup will be greater.